# SQLite or Preferences

Tags: android, sqlite

I was trying to build a music player in android and I require to save the playlist created by the user. Now I was looking for SQLite and found that there exist a thing called preferences. Now what will be best for me in terms for memory and structure and ease in data-retrieval?

Thanks in advance,
A Noob. 
:)

Comment: Search for a question like this next time. Look up what each entails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a playlist DEFINITELY the database. The preferences is just a simple key-value pair.

Comment: Nothing to think about.  Preferences are for storing app options and the like.  Definitely not playlists.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the complexity of what you are going to save. SharedPreferences it's the simple approach, but I don't think it is a good idea in terms of scalability.

In your case you would be better off using SQLite just because you can create complex structures using a relational database and still being easy to develop because its well-known SQL syntax.

Comment: I am looking to save the songname, its path(or maybe not I will have to see) and the genre. So will the preferences fail in such a scenario because from what little I read it said something about key value pairs? So guessing it to be something like HashMap will it fail to fulfill my needs?

Comment: I mean, it's not that is impossible but it's definitely NOT a good idea. About the HashMap it's useful in runtime but you can't store it. But you can always create the tables you need and store the HashMap information in them.

Anyway, for your requirements, don't even bother with SharedPreferences. Go for SQLite.

Comment: Yeah sure I know that HashMap cant be stored. :P I was just comparing to the fact that both deal with key value PAIRS... so if I want 2 values(fields) for a key that wont be possible for preferences I guess..:)

Comment: Yes, they both work that way. And you could develop a really really scary and planly unmaintainable, inefficient and hacky. It's not worth it at all. At all. SharedPreferences are not for that.